# how can get highligted word from pdf file?

Tags: java, pdf

I develope new program  but i need to allow user to highlighting word in pdf file then i want to process the file to get list of highlighted words with place

how can do that by java

thank in advance

Comment: Are you sure that the *highlight* attributes on text are stored in the pdf file? Did a quick test with Adobe Reader with no success...

Answer (score 0):

PDF files are PostScript, which is very difficult to process.  I doubt there's an easy way.

Take a look at http://java-source.net/open-source/pdf-libraries , but be aware you might have some difficulty.

Also, read http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/pdf/HighlightFileFormat.pdf for the specs of the highlight format.  Depending on what "place" information you need, that might be enough.

Answer (score 0):

How are you displaying the PDF? If you are displaying the image, you just need the word co-ordinates. Something like PdfBox or JPedal or maybe IText can do this.